# Spring data MongoDB multiple databases

Tags: mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I was wondering if spring data for MongoDB could handle multiple databases and perform cross database queries and inserts.

for example if I want to store `EntityA` in DB `dbA` and `EntityB` in `dbB`  and `EntityA` has a reference to `EntityB`, will Spring Data generate the correct `DBRef` pointing to the correct collection and the correct database ?

Will I then be able to query `EntityA` and then eventually lazy fetch `EntityB` ?

**Morphia** lacks this functionality alongside other things, and I was wondering if Spring data had it before making the big dive and ditching Morphia.

Comment: I'd be interested in the answer too, this is a valuable question. However, I think you should try it out on just a Hello World like setup, and report back your findings as an answer... I think it would help future finders of this page a lot!

Answer (score 1):

The `DbRef` annotation has a `db` attribute so that you can define the database the reference will be stored in. So assuming a model like this:

```
class EntityA {
  @DbRef(db = "dbB") EntityB entityB;
}

class EntityB { … }

interface ARepository extends Repository<EntityA, Long> { … }
interface BRepository extends Repository<EntityB, Long> { … }
```

you're client code should look something like this:

```
EntityB b = new EntityB(…);
EntityA a = new EntityA(…);
a.setB(b);

// store A manually first   
aRepository.save(a);
bRepository.save(b);
```

Comment: Thanks Oliver. I tried setting the db attribute on the annotation but it seems the $db field of the DBRef is not written in the database. Is this normal ? Does Spring have its own way of fetching back the entity from the second database without the $db field ? Thanks.